# dict comprehension in python

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

New to python, and am learning about dict comprehension online. i saw this snippet of code but do not understand how it work.

[image]

i understand this dict comprehension `{k: D[k] for k in D.keys()` but please help me understand  `- removeKeys}`. I do not understand how the result to be. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: How about `{k: D[k] for k in D.keys() if k not in removeKeys}`?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's understand list comprehension.

**List Comprehension:**

```
x = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> Output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Now, similary in dict comprehension we use the same syntax. However, dicts have `key: value` pairs and hence that's how you need to do it.

**Dict Comprehension:**
What the above code is doing:

- Get the keys of `D` dict and remove the keys `0, 2, 5`.
- Iterate over the remaining keys and generate a `key: value` based on `D` dict.

Comment: thanks for comment. but how does it remove keys `0, 2, 5`?

Comment: `D.keys()` returns a `list` of the keys of the `D` dict. And, you can subtract two lists. So, `D.keys() - removeKeys` simply does this: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] - [0, 2, 5`. Please mark the answer correct if it helped you :)

Comment: You can *not* subtract two lists. You can however do subtraction with sets, and `dict.keys()` returns a set-like view.

Comment: so `{k: D[k] for k in D.keys() - removeKeys}` under the hood is `list(set(dict.keys() - set(removeKeys))` ?

Comment: @trt Sort of but not really. `dict.keys()` returns an object (a key view) which supports the `-` operator. As the right-hand-side of that `dict.keys() -` operations, it appears to take any *iterable*. I.e. conceptually it's defined as `set() - set()`, but in practice it's implemented more leniently as *set-like minus any-iterable*.